# Checking whether a given sample is stationary

Tags: stationarity

Let $x[n]$ be some time series in 1D or $x[m,n]$ in 2D, of length $N$ (resp. $N^2$) How can I assess whether it is *stationary*? At least in the weak sense. I can check whether the *stdev* remains constant, but this is only a necessary condition.

Comment: http://lojze.lugos.si/~darja/software/r/library/tseries/html/adf.test.html  The Augmented Dickey Fuller is a test that is often used.  here is the R package for the test.

Comment: I have tried to use `adftest` on my own series of an antipersistent fractional Brownian motion (i.e., H<0.5) and the ADFtest rejected the null hypotheses, i.e. identified it as stationary. While it is short-range dependent -- it is definitely not stationary.

Comment: if it isn't stationary, have you considered first differencing the time series and checking again for stationarity?

Comment: I am only doing this by simulation; with my real `x[n]`, I do not know whether it is stationary or not. Let us say I am given (unknowingly) an fBm with H<0.5, a nonstationary series, then the test will fail...